# slope function in excel

Tags: python, excel, statistics, linear-regression, intercept

I need to create a wind shear exponent timeseries and historically have used the slope function in excel. if you scatter plot the log of heights and the log of the windspeeds, the resulting slope is the shear exponent. What is the best method to recreate this in python?
Suppose I have a df containing wind speeds at 40,60,80m and wish to create a new column with the resulting wind shear exponent.

thanks

Comment: So you want to recreate the maths behind the slope function?

Comment: So, the question isn't about Excel, it is python?